# How to add multidimensional array values in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 52 weeks array's and each week array has a sub array with 9 values.
now I need to add a value 0 at the begin of each array and every next week I need 1 value more.

For example (notice that the 0-8 will be in a for loop)

```
    $vruchtzettings_week["week1"][0-8] = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    $vruchtzettings_week["week2"][0-8] = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    $vruchtzettings_week["week3"][0-8] = 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    $vruchtzettings_week["week4"][0-8] = 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: Yes, you need to be using a `for` loop.

Comment: Fix your question title please. In a list of questions it tells me _nothing_ about this question (other than, frankly, to avoid it...)

Comment: it's php, there is no way.

Comment: eum a good link to find answers to this question: http://www.google.com

Comment: just write down loops for each statement (sum) and then you'll see how to write second loop.

Comment: Are you sure the code above is correct? Why do you start over on week 10 with `$totaal["week1"][0]`. Are you meaning `$totaal["week1"][10]`?

Comment: loop will be the best option. but can consider recursive function as an option

Comment: @mseifert no each array has $totaal["week1"][0-8] then goes to $totaal["week2"][0-8]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I can't really test it, I believe this would do it for you. What you're doing is *really convoluted.*

```
$week = 1;
while ($week <= 52) {
  $sum = 0;

  for ($sub = 0; $sub < 9; $sub++, $week++;) {
    $totaal_vruchtzetting_week[$week] = $totaal["week$week"][$sub] + $sum;
    $sum += $totaal["week$week"][$sub];
  }
}
```

Like I said, you will probably have to tweek this a little. But it will get you started.